# Problem with gpg --recv-keys

Tags: cassandra, pgp, gnupg, apt-get

I am trying to install cassandra using apt-get on Ubuntu.

I added this to my /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian unstable main
deb-src http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian unstable main

Then:

sudo apt-get update

Then:

W: GPG error: http://www.apache.org unstable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F758CE318D77295D

Then I took the number NO_PUBKEY:

gpg --keyserver wwwkeys.eu.pgp.net --recv-keys F758CE318D77295D

But then I get an error:

gpg: requesting key ... from hkp server wwwkeys.eu.pgp.net
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error

What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: in a dockerfile you may have to change the domain name of the key server by the ip adress

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this instead for the GPG key addition:

```
gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys F758CE318D77295D
gpg --export --armor F758CE318D77295D | sudo apt-key add -
```